# Drop row in Pandas dataframe if zero bordered by numbers (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

Due to some foibles in the API I'm using, sometimes a 'Zero' is returned when it should return a number; which works its way through to a Pandas dataframe that my script outputs (Python).

[image]

What would be a Pythonic way to drop a row if a zero is bordered both above and below by non-zero numbers? I can think of extensive loops to solve this, but that'd be quite an intensive way of going about this.

Note that elsewhere in the dataframe there'll be continuous rows of zeros, which are valid, so it's not simply a case of dropping all rows with zeros in them; I only want to drop rows with zero if they're bordered by rows with *valid* non-zero numbers.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Dropping rows with any zeros in them (i.e. any column) that resemble the one above, so it is no longer in the dataframe. However, if there are multiple consecutive rows with zeros in them (in any column), leave them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `col` is the column you want to filter on, and it's type is `str` (drop `"` if it's `float`):

```py
df = df.loc[~ (df["col"].shift(-1).ne("0.0") & df["col"].eq("0.0") & df["col"].shift(1).ne("0.0"))]
```